# I don't see any difference between viewScope and flashScope. Need more information about these two scopes

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

code snippet:

```
<view-state id="f1" view="f1.jsp">
    <on-entry>
        <set name="flashScope.wish" value="'Hello'"/>
    </on-entry>
    <transition on="next" to="f2"/>
</view-state>

<view-state id="f2" view="f2.jsp">
</view-state>
```

In f1 view state, a variable with name wish stored in flash scope. But it is not visible in next view f2.jsp. How to make wish variable visible without using flow scope and conversation scope?

Answer (score 1):

Flash scope attributes are available until the next view is rendered, view scope attributes are available until the current view exits.

see [ScopeType](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/ScopeType.html#REQUEST)